# Running Selenium script in JMeter is not working

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, jmeter

I have created the Selenium Web Driver script in intelliJ IDEA and after that, I have created the Jar file of the selenium script and configured the jar file in JMeter_Home/lib.

Then, Created the Test Plan in JMeter in which added the JUnit Request sampler with Class Name, Method Name and also added the Listners (View Result Tree).

On running the Test plan its not working. So, how can I resolve this?

Comment: What exactly is not working? And what do you expect JMeter to do?

Comment: I want my Selenium Web driver script to run in JMeter to perform load testing

Comment: You can run your Selenium tests from your IDE and use JMeter as proxy. Just start JMeter and configure its host/port for your WebDriver instance. The tests are run with JMeter between Browser and web application and JMeter records the test session, which you can later run from Jmeter command-line. Step by step Tutorial is here: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should put your .jar file with tests to `lib/junit` folder
2. You also need to place all the Selenium dependency jars into `lib` folder (or any other folder on the [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
3. In case of any problems first of all check *jmeter.log* file, in majority of cases it has enough troubleshooting information
4. It may be easier to use [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) plugin instead of running Selenium tests through JUnit

Check out [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more details on running JUnit tests via JMeter